# Tratando ficheros con pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

**El enunciado es el siguiente, agradecería cualquier ayuda:**

Almacene los datos de la base de datos descargada para poder trabajar con ellos en Jupyter Notebook. (Importe primero la librería “pandas” y haga que se pueda usar con el acrónimo “pd”). Lea el fichero de datos Excel descargado y almacénelo en una variable la función read_excel de pandas.

(Por ejemplo, para leer Mifichero y almacenarlo en MiVariable, tendría que usar la siguiente instrucción: MiVariable = pd.read_excel("MiFichero.xls"). Calcule el número de datos, obtenga los 7 primeros y diga cómo se llama la columna de datos. A partir de este punto, si quiere utilizar los datos numéricos solamente, debe usar la última columna, usando por ejemplo la siguiente asignación:

MisDatos = MiVariable.iloc[:, Nc], en el que Nc es el número de la columna. No puede usar estos nombres de variable en su trabajo, cambie dichos nombres por los suyos propios

**Quería saber si el siguiente código estructurado es correcto o debo modificar algo. En caso de que deba modificar algo, si podeis editar mi respuesta lo agradeceria**

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

file = "Data_Extract_From_World_Development_Indicators.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname = "Data", na_values = "n/a")
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
num_datos = len(df.index)   # Calcular el número de datos
display(df.head(7))         # Obtener los siete primero
nombre_col = df.columns[-1] # Nombre de la columna de datos
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo del primer párrafo y la mitad del segundo lo tienes. En cuanto al resto:

### Calcular el número de datos

Si no lo he malentendido sería simplemente saber las filas de la tabla, puedes hacerlo de dos formas:

- Comprobando la longitud del índice:

  ```
  num_datos = len(df.index)
  ```
- Usando `pandas.DataFrame.shape`:

  ```
  num_datos = df.shape[0]
  ```

### Obtener los 7 primeros

Con `pandas.DataFrame.head` que ya intentas usar puedes mostrar las 7 primeras filas simplemente pasando 7 como argumento:

```
df.head(7)
```

Si solo quieras mostrar los siete primeros valores (última columna):

```
df.iloc[:, -1]
```

### Nombre de la columna de datos

Como nos dicen que es la última, basta con indizar sobre `pandas.DataFrame.columns`:

```
nombre_col = df.columns[-1]
```

Python permite indizado negativo, -1 es el índice del último elemento. Su índice positivo sería simplemente el número de columnas menos uno:

```
ind_ultima_col = len(np.columns) - 1
```

O si quieres el indice de una columna sabiendo su nombre puedes usar `get_loc`:

```
ind_col = df.columns.get_loc("nombre_columna")
```

Comment: Un módulo de Python estándar y un NoteBook no son lo mismo, los NoteBooks tienen extensión .ipynb y los archivos Python .py, de todas forma la extensión no sirve para nada excepto en Windows que las usa para asociar el programa a usar. Si te piden que trabajes con NoteBook crea uno nuevo en el navegador para no complicarte como ya has hecho pega el código y guardalo, eso se guardará como .ipynb y podrás abrirlo desde cualquier lado usando Jupyter. Eso si,  solo se puede abrir en Jupyter no en un intérprete Python estándar.

Comment: Instala xlrd con pip (p.e `python -m pip install xlrd`) igual que instalaste pandas o jupyterlab

Comment: Lo instalé pero me sigue mostrando el mismo error. No sé si el código está bien porque antes de ese error me apareció uno relacionado con la insrtuccion de sheetname

Comment: Primero, si te sigue dando el mismo error es casi seguro que no has instalado en el intérprete/entorno que Jupyter está usando, vete a tu NoteBook de Jupyter y en una celda vacía coloca `%pip install xlrd`, ejecuta la celda y espera a que temine. Reinicia el kernel y luego ejecuta tu celda con el código de pandas, no debería haber ningún problema si la instalación fue correcta, la celda con pip puedes eliminrla.

Comment: Por cierto, tenías un typo, no me había dado cuenta, el nombre del argumento no es `sheetname` es `sheet_name`, puede que éste fuera el error al que te referías.